# How to repair damaged (corrupted) images?

Tags: windows-xp, images, repair

I have deleted accidentally some photos from my computer. I have restored them using  program, but some of them open as a black page. When I want to open with paint it says: "paint cannot read this file. This is not a valid bitmap, file or its format is not currently supported. i use Windows xp. I tried to recover them with https://online.officerecovery.com/pixrecovery/ but some of them still don't recover. I found a website to repair corrupted files and it says that if I don't have a Windows XP CD (which I don't), I should put a file named "i386" at the computer root. i don't understand the other part. Is there any Other possibility to repair these files? What about this method I mentioned, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Is there any Other possibility to repair these files?**

Probably not. Parts of these files were overwritten when you continued to use the computer. Especially when you downloaded, installed and ran other recovery software.

Normal recovery process is to stop using the disk containing the photos. This usually means booting from a recovery CD or bootable USB (prpeared on a separate computer) - see other answers here.

> **What about this method I mentioned**

The method that mentioned XP CD-ROMs and i386 is probably about repairing damaged files that are part of the  Windows operating system itself, not about repairing photo-image files.

> **how can it be done?**

It probably can't.

Some of your photos are probably permanently lost.

This is why, for the last 65 years, sensible people make multiple independent offline backup copies of important photos and other data. Don't rely on a single cloud provider or other single media, test recovery from backup. Unfortunately, each new generation of people have to learn this lesson themselves the hard way. We have no effective means of teaching children the usefulness of this.

> **i use Windows xp.**

You are aware that Microsoft no longer support XP and no longer provide security updates for this in the normal way? It is no longer safe to connect an XP system to the Internet.

> **I don't have any malware because I have a powerful antivirus**

No AV product is 100% effective. Especially one for an obsolete operating system. See [zero-day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-day_(computing))